# How to use referer condition in Amazon S3 bucket policy with CloudFront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

**Requirement:**

> We're using AWS CloudFront with S3 bucket for my client to save the tutorial/course videos, hence we would like to prevent the users to download any video with the links either **S3 Object link** or **CloudFront** domain url. In other words only with our website these will be readable / accessible or users can only be able to watch them. Therefore, we're trying to restrict the access through direct links.

**Tried solution:**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "S3PublicRead",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectTagging",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectTagging"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::DOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET",
                "arn:aws:s3:::DOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "aws:Referer": [
                        "https://dev.mycompany.com/",
                        "https://mycompany.com/"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "CloudFrontPublicRead",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity AAAAAAAAAAA"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::DOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET",
                "arn:aws:s3:::DOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "aws:Referer": [
                        "https://dev.mycompany.com/",
                        "https://mycompany.com/"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**Problem:**

> The above policy is working fine with the S3 object urls, like If I open it through the link it is showing **Access Denied** and within my website the videos are playing fine.
> However, the video links with CloudFront Domain, not accessible even within the website. We need the same behavior as with the S3 direct URLs.

**Conclusion:**

> The **aws:Referer** condition is working fine with s3 object urls but not applying on the CloudFront url, hence making them unaccessible.

Hopefully, I'm able to state the problem as it is occurring.

Thanks in advance.

**More Info:**

**Cloudfront Distribution Behavior Details:**

- Listing
  [image: Behavior listings]
- Details of the second entry (Default)
  [image: Behavior settings]

Comment: Can you share what error you are getting when accessing via cloudfront url, also if you can share the behaviour settings that will be great

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that CloudFront doesn't forward request headers. To achieve this you can:

1. In CloudFront Cache Behavior settings, create a new 'Origin request policy' to forward (only) 'Referer' (try to be specific because when using 'All viewer headers' you can get SignatureDoesNotMatch error from S3), and then filter by this params in your bucket policy.

[image]

More info about this approach in: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/RequestAndResponseBehaviorCustomOrigin.html#request-custom-headers-behavior

OR,

2. Use Web ACLs with rules filtering string match conditions on Referer as described in:  https://aws.amazon.com/pt/blogs/security/how-to-prevent-hotlinking-by-using-aws-waf-amazon-cloudfront-and-referer-checking/ (Additional monthly price of $5/ACL + $1/rule)